# Add variable prefix to angular routing

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I am trying to update an old BackBone.js app to Angular (4/5).
One of the requirements is to keep using the old routes in this new app, which triggers some challenges.

The old routes are build as follows:

```
site.com/r/{username}/{route}
```

e.g.

```
site.com/r/johndoe/homepage
site.com/r/janedoe/blog
```

I'm now using Angular routing without hash, but every route i build in Angular now consists of a long string:

```
{ path: '/r/:username/homepage' }
```

I'm hoping there is a cleaner way to uses routes in here.
The :username variable is only needed when bootstrapping the app, so it would be a lot nicer to strip the first bit off of the Url and start NG route paths after this.

I know base href will compile the app to a potential subdirectory, but this will not work with the variable username.

Is there a way to make this work in Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'r',
   component: AppComponent,
   children: [
      { path: ':username/homepage', component: HomePageComponent },
      // other children or you can use loadChildren
   ]
 }
];
```

https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a better approach. Since i only want to use the :username when bootstrapping the app, i came up with this:
`{
    path: 'r/:username',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'homepage', component: HomePageComponent' }
    ]
}`

Answer (score 7):

Or you can do this, it is really brief, and should do the same

https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

usage:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the base URL would change based on the client using our software.

This article was perfect for my solution: https://medium.com/@anandshende1994/setting-base-href-dynamically-in-angular-6-b7fe824848cf

In index.html

```
<script>
  window['base-href'] = window.location.pathname;
  console.log(window['base-href']);
</script>
```

In app.module.ts (providers section):

```
  {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: window['base-href']
  }
```